# JDBC connectivity in JSP

Tags: jsp, jdbc

I am new to Web Development. I have a small problem in my code.
This is my JSP code, and whatever value I enter in the textbox, it is stored as null in the database. Please do help me out.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type ="text" name ="movies">
    <input type ="submit" name ="submit">
    <%   String rating = request.getParameter("submit");
         try{
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shoppingmgmt","root","admin");
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            int rs = st.executeUpdate("insert into movies values('"+rating+"')");
            out.println("success");

         }catch(Exception e){
             out.println(e);

         }

    %>
</body>
```

Comment: You should not have code like this embedded in your JSP.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried debugging your code? The following line uses the value of the `submit` button as the rating:

```
String rating = request.getParameter("submit")
```

...change it to the following to get the value of the `text` input:

```
String rating = request.getParameter("movies")
```